# Catching cancel or dismiss for TimePicker

Tags: android

I'm not sure how to implement an onCancel/onDismiss listener to the code below. Could somebody please assist.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;
                    time = ""+mHour+":"+mMinute;
                    notifications();
                }
    };



@Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Edit: Working code is below. When you click set it does it's thing. Anything else it removed the checkbox.

```
        @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            TimePickerDialog myTime = new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
            myTime.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Log.d("IN HERE","HERE2");
                    cbChecked = false;
                    notValue = 0;
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    checkBox.setText("Use reminders");
                }
            });
            return myTime;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning the `TimePickerDialog` directly like you are on the `onCreateDialog` method, you should instantiate it and add a `onCancel` listener.

```
...
case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
   TimePickerDialog myTime = new TimePickerDialog(this,yourListener, h, m, false);
   myTime(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
      @Override
      public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
        //your stuff
      }
   );//For cancel button

   return myTime; //Return the dialog
break;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting an error still. Could you take a look at the edited section in my question please.

Comment: Sometimes the `onCancel` event is handled by the `onDismiss` method instead for some reason, so try doing the same thing you did with `setOnCancelListener` with `setOnDismissListener` (not sure if that's the actual name)

Comment: It goes in there now. It just doesn't remove the check from the checkbox, which is another issue entirely. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, actually. The dismiss is called even when the "set" it clicked for the picker. So.. cancel would be the only one working.